# Return SQL query in one row, fetch with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

With my SQL query, I want to counter up all the distinct values in a certain column. This works fine:

```
SELECT ans, COUNT(*) AS ans_num
FROM table_123
GROUP BY ans;
```

This returns (depending on how many distinct values) something like this, if there were three distinct values in the table:

```
+------+---------+
| ans  | ans_num |
+------+---------+
| 0    |      15 |
| 1    |       2 |
| 3    |      11 |
+------+---------+
```

I'm using `mysqli_fetch_array` to return the query values in PHP, but I would have to loop through each row in order to get all the results.

## QUESTION:

How can I write an SQL query that would return all the distinct values in one array (associative), so I would only have to `mysqli_fetch_array` only once?

## CLARIFICATION:

I was wondering if there's a way in the query to return the results of the query as a single row, not fetching all rows with PHP

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all

Comment: you alredy get an associative array but it is inside a normal array `[[["ans"=>0], ["ans_num" => 15]], [["ans"=>1], ["ans_num" => 2]], [["ans"=>3], ["ans_num" => 11]]]`...

Comment: Why don't you use distinct in mysql query `SELECT DISTINCT ans, COUNT(*) AS ans_num
FROM table_123
GROUP BY category;` USING `mysqli_fetch_all`

Comment: try mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way in the query to return the results of the query as a single row, not fetching all rows with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is only possible if you have a determinate number of values for "ans".  Something like this should work in that case.

```
    SELECT SUM(Zero) "0", Sum(One) "1", Sum(Two) "2", Sum(Three) "3" FROM
        (SELECT IF(ans=0, 1, 0) Zero, IF(ans=1, 1, 0) One, IF(ans=2, 1, 0) Two, IF(ans=3, 1, 0) Three
        FROM table_123) TEMP;
```

This should get you a result like this:

```
    +---+----+----+----+
    | 0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |
    +---+----+----+----+
    | 15|   2|   0|  11|
    +---+----+----+----+
```

If the number of possible values is too large for this approach, you may want to look into pivot tables.  If the number of possible values is indeterminate, I'm not sure how you could effect what you are requesting.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I've since learned this is just a huge mistake to try and get my data this way. Good for future reference, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this? 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php
Or I understand you wrong?